# @ngrx/store pre-load guard catch error

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I'm working on the Angular guard with @ngrx/store to check if state has been already loaded and I faced an issue that `canActivate` method never returns if I use filter.

Here is an example effect for GetCompanies action:

```
return this.companiesService.getCompanies()
  .pipe(
    map(companies => new companiesActions.GetCompaniesSuccess(companies)),
    catchError(error => Observable.of(new companiesActions.GetCompaniesFail(error)))
  )
```

If there is an error I'm dispatching a GetCompaniesFail action and redirect a user to `/login` page. That's fine, the interesting part is with the guard.

```
@Injectable()
export class CompaniesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.checkStore()
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => Observable.of(true)),
        catchError(() => Observable.of(false))
      );
  }

  checkStore(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.select(getCompaniesLoaded)
      .pipe(
        tap(loaded => {
          if (!loaded) {
            this.store.dispatch(new companiesActions.GetCompanies());
          }
        }),
        filter(loaded => loaded),
        take(1)
      );
  }
}
```

If there is an error and loaded is not false, `canActivate` wouldn't return anything because `checkStore` does nothing.

If I change `filter` to `map` it works but it takes only the first value which is `false` even if the data will be loaded successfully.

What am I missing? How can I handle HTTP errors there? Is there a way to either wait for certain state or throw an error inside `checkStore`?

Thank in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure you should make http calls in guards. This means that on every page change, you will make an http request. Not only this is useless requests, but in case of a user that pays for its internet, you will make him pay for unecessary requests. Are you sure you want to do that ? What exactly is the condition your guard is testing ?

Comment: @trichetriche I think that his plan is to make the call, put the data in cache (ngrx), and reference that from then on. The problem is that it isn't in cache on first page load. At least that was my issue.

Comment: I had the same situation and I solved it by setting up my effect to retry on error. What is your desired result on an error? Do you want `canActivate` to emit false?

Answer (score 1):

This seems easier to handle if you separate the responsibilities a little.

You should run `checkStore` regardless, and not depend on it's result directly. Instead, let the store inform you of success or failure and return that result.

Note that ngrx and redux encourages ***one-way-data-flow*** to simplify app logic.

The store property `getCompaniesLoadedStatus` in initialized to *initial*, and set to *success* or *failed* within `companiesActions.GetCompaniesSuccess` or `companiesActions.GetCompaniesFail`.

Retries are handled in the service (closer to the fetch).

```js
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  this.checkStore();
  return this.store.select(getCompaniesLoadedStatus).pipe(
    filter(status => status !== 'initial'),
    map(status => status === 'success' ? true : false )
  );
}

checkStore(): void {
  this.store.select(getCompaniesLoadedStatus).pipe(
    take(1)  // so that unsubscribe is not needed
  ).subscribe(status =>
    if (status === 'initial') { 
      this.store.dispatch(new companiesActions.GetCompanies());
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: That is interesting, I can have three values instead of two, then it is easier. With this approach it is possible to return Observable straight from the checkStore with `filter(status => status !== 'initial'` and then in canActivate check `return this.checkStore().pipe(switchMap(status => status === 'success' ? true : false))`

Comment: It sounds like you may have missed the point, which is that `canActivate` should be decoupled from `checkStore`. In fact, the way I do it is to do the checking in the service.